# How to Export Blog Posts from SharePoint Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint, blogs, sharepoint-2007

I have a team site blog with many posts that I wish to export. I don't see any option outside of exporting the post titles to an Excel sheet. Any ideas? OPML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently moved my blog from SharePoint to WordPress using BlogML. I first came across it in  a post from Chad Gross - [Migrating your SharePoint blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/cgross/archive/2009/09/05/migrating-your-sharepoint-blog.aspx)

That method involves connecting through Access, which I don't have set up, so I ended up making my own BlogMLWriter that connects directly to the SharePoint object model based on the ones in codeplex for other platforms. I'm happy to send the code if you need it before I get around to finishing the writeup.

Comment: Tom, looks like a solution but a lot of work for what I want. +1 and pending answer ;-)

Comment: I'd like to mention the Access solution is **very** easy to work with, so it might be worth spending a bit of time setting that up instead of making some custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the given solution did not work for me, either. I ultimately had to create a new view that showed everything. Then, I could switch to that view and export the posts into a spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, any pictures included in the posts do not get exported. Frankly, it's a pain in the butt.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it the following way:

Go to site action -> site settings -> modify all site settings -> site libraries and lists-> posts->

Again click on the post in the breadcrumbs. Then you reached in post library. From there you can export it to Excel.

Comment: No such navigation. After I navigate Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Libraries and Lists, the only option I see is to "Customize Posts" which doesn't help.

Comment: you need to click on the post link in the bread cramp then you can see the option